# python script to move another object when a certain object is moved

Tags: python

Suppose I have a cube and a sphere. I want to write a python script such that when I move the cube by a vector `(x,y,z)`, the sphere also moves by the same vector. I want to be able to move the cube by hand, and have the sphere move automatically. I realize that I can do this by selecting both before moving, but I would like to accomplish this with code. Is this possible?

Comment: Does it really have to be with code? I mean there are a bunch of built in tools to accomplish this, like say parenting, constraints, setting up relations that are much easier.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos This is partly out of curiosity, and also partly due to a possible scenario in which I would have too many objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [drivers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/drivers/index.html) to do this, or use a constraint. The constraint is probably the fastest option (performance-wise), as they are written in C.

If you want you can even add drivers or constraints via Python, in case you want to have scripted control over those.

Comment: I didn't know about drivers. Thanks for pointing this out!